# Export gridview to excel having numeric column

Tags: asp.net

I want to export my gridview to excel. One column contains a numeric value, like:

> 12345678998765432112345678899

but when I am exporting to excel, it is showing like:

> 1234+E11

I don't want like this,I want entire value.

I used following code

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.Buffer = true;
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ReportOutput.xls");
 Response.Charset = "";
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

 System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
 System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);

 hw.WriteLine("<h3>Output Form</h3>");

 GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
 string style = "<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\\@; } </style>";

 Response.Write(style);
 Response.Output.Write(tw.ToString());
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
```

Still it is not working.